# Why public void disableShortcuts (List<String> shortcutIds) don't work with Static Shortcuts

Tags: java, android

i have a code that disables the static and Dynamic shortcuts but it work well with the Dynamic
and when put static shortcut is it's get IllegalStateException i don't why.
also the documentation for the [public void disableShortcuts (List shortcutIds)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ShortcutManager#disableShortcuts(java.util.List%3Cjava.lang.String%3E))
say it can add the static shortcuts.

Here is the code

```
shortcutManager.disableShortcuts(Arrays.asList( "compose" /*Static Shortcut*/, shortcut.getId()/*Dynamic Shortcut*/ ));
```

and if this method cant work with static shortcuts how to set static shortcuts disabled but dynamically form the java code ?

Comment: as per documentation `IllegalStateException` thrown `when the user is locked.` is it the case with you?

Comment: your user was locked?

Comment: I am sill new in stackoverflow and don't now why this happen